# How can i disable channel list url?

Tags: craft3, routes, channels

I have a channel type entry where I'm inserting services. I have created a channel and add route `services/{slug}` and added template `services\_entry.twig`. I want to keep url for single service as `services/single-service` but want to disable "services" route.

For example:

```
localhost/services/single-service    // Need to keep it
localhost/services                   // Need to disable
```

Is it possible in Craft CMS?

Answer (score 3):

Craft doesn't have any default routes for the frontend. So if you're seeing anything else than a 404 page on your `/services` route, it's because you've put something there. The [routing documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html) has a list of possible sources for the content you're seeing for that route. Most likely, you have either:

- a section with an entry that has `services` as its URI
- a template called `services.twig` in your templates folder
- or a route matching that URL (defined in the backend or in `config/routes.php`)

To remove the `/services` route from the frontend, use the list linked above to find out where it's coming from and then disable it.